# enterprise application packaging & deployment with netbeans 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb-3.0, ear

I'm having issues with deployment of my enterprise application. I have my entities in a separate project (as class library) and my remote interfaces as well. So I have theses projects linked to each other in multiple ways:

- ejb module
- war
- entities (class library)
- remote interfaces (class library)
- enterprise app client

**Everything worked fine for a while**, meaning the dependencies were fine at some point, then suddenly I can't deploy anymore and I have this error:
`remote-project.clean:`
(...)

`FacadeRemote.java:3: package entities does not exist`

followed by a long list of  `cannot find symbol`

This only happens when I try to deploy, *clean and build* works perfectly and I haven't changed anything in the dependencies, not knowingly at least.

I think this is related to netbeans because I've fixed it earlier by reverting changes (not made by me) to some `private.properties` files (no such luck this time). One of the lines I removed was `javac.debug=true` which might be a lead but I've tried to disable debugging without success.

I'm not comfortable with EAR packaging so I'm probably missing something important, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same problem with netbeans/glassfish setup. I had ejbs in a separate module as jar, and deploying the project form netbeans into glassfish caused similar errors. I notied that if I clean the glassfish deployment manually, and build the project manually, and then, yep, still manually deployed it into glassfish it worked ok.

My solution? Installed eclipse for java ee, added the glassfish connector, and deploying from eclipse to glassfish never presented this errors

Comment: Indeed manual deployment works, I can use that for now. That confirms that the issue is with netbeans, I'll keep searching that way.

Comment: Well good luck with that, but there's slim hope. I had the same issue back on netbeans 5.x. I'm guessing you're using netbeans 7 or whatever the current version is. Since they didn't fix it across 2+ major versions, I don't think you'll find a fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the "Compile on Save" feature in the EAR project.